# MTOUCH: error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly iPhone/Debug/build-iphone7.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/Build/xxx.exe

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

In Xamarin Studio v6.1.3 with Xamarin.iOS v10.3.1.7 / Cycle8, I'm experiencing the following error when trying to build an exe for Debug/iPhone

> MTOUCH: error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly iPhone/Debug/build-iphone7.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/Build/myapp.exe

I've already followed the steps from other questions to enable verbose log output for MTouch, to enable Link All for SDKs and to look at the output window. There was one easy-to-fix error but now I can't see why AOT is failing.

[image]

Here's an excerpt of the build log file:

```
MTOUCH: error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/.../obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone7.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/Build/myapp.exe'
          at Xamarin.Bundler.AOTTask.Build () [0x00117] in <e7bcfe3010854457a2ec851b72b35cf0>:0 
          at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask.Execute () [0x00000] in <e7bcfe3010854457a2ec851b72b35cf0>:0 
          at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTasks.Execute (Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask v) [0x00000] in <e7bcfe3010854457a2ec851b72b35cf0>:0 
          at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+<ForEachWorker>c__AnonStorey6`2[TSource,TLocal].<>m__0 (System.Int32 i) [0x00012] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
          at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+<ForWorker>c__AnonStorey3`1[TLocal].<>m__1 () [0x000ed] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
    Task "MTouch" execution -- FAILED
    Done building target "_CompileToNative" in project "/...myapp.csproj".-- FAILED
```

Other than that, nothing. No errors. A bazillion warnings though ...

Full log is on the following OneDrive link: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AjQxIVxoV2Ypg4YP_JPAcZF92KLAcQ

Any ideas? :S

Comment: What have you tried yourself to resolve the issue? I don't want to provide an solution that you have already tried

Comment: Oh gosh, trawled the web for similar errors (which there are many). Most seem to be resolved by updating Xamarin Studio and Xamarin.iOS I'm on the latest so that didn't work. Some are resolved by setting Link All in properties window, or Link Some, or Link None. Also didn't work. Some are resolved by clean / delete bin/obj and a restart. Also didn't work. One or two are resolved by putting command line args -v -v -v -v in MTouch and viewing the log. I did that, and successfully solved ONE problem which was in our code, but the log gives no clue to the second one ... :/

Comment: I suspect either: a bug in Xamarin (very possible) or something todo with the hundreds of warnings we have in the log file. Hard to say, the error message provides no clue sadly ...

Comment: Alright, seems you also stumbled upon the same threads as me. Could you possibly have [white spaces in your project path](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9402/could-not-aot-the-assembly-mt3001)? If that's not the case either, I'd strongly suggest that you post a bug on [Xamarin's bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/). This is not a new issue unfortunately, and has appeared in many different varieties.

Comment: Sadly no white spaces :( I did create a bug on bugzilla, about a week ago https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=50760. Thanks for commenting anyway, if you think of anything, feel free to post :)

Comment: Will do. Best of luck :)

Comment: Seems this is a Xamarin bug. At least, the team at Bugzilla have responded and can reproduce a crash in AOT compiler. They're working on it \o/

Comment: I am currently binding an iOS library too and stumbled upon this message. During my searching I read somewhere that the reason could be that the assembly is so big that iOS can not handle this. To solve this a way to go is to enable linking and LLVM optimization.

Comment: After looking at your log file I think the reason for failing is within your binding project. Can you share it somewhere?

Comment: Hi Tequila, I'm afraid I can't, its proprietary. However, I would suggest strongly reporting a bug at bugzilla.xamarin.com with steps / code to reproduce and they should be able to help.

Comment: Hi @tequilaslammer check my answer below. Might be a solution for you

Comment: @Dr.ABT You can check the included platforms of a framework with lipo -info path_to_framework_or_.a_file

Answer (score 0):

We have a solution from the [excellent team at Xamarin](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=50760):

1. It seems our Framework library does not include ARM7 and ARM64 slices. This is part of the reason why the AOT step is failing.
2. Another part is a bug in Xamarin.iOS which was fixed for 10.4.0.67 version or later.
3. The Xamarin AOT compiler will be updated to output better error messages about why this has failed + fix the error in the next cycle 10.4.0.67 or later